# Is it possible to schedule same task at different cron in celery without duplicating entry

Tags: cron, celery, cron-task, celerybeat

I want to schedule a celery task at random possible days and also on last day of every month. Is it possible to store the schedule of a celery task in certain way that the task gets picked up both in middle of the month and the last day of month as well. Last day of month of course is not static. Is it possible to store two different cron expressions for single task. I tried a cron expression with L for last month as suggested in many sites. but it doesn't seem to be a standard.

Comment: I do not think it is possible without having two different entries in the beat config...

Comment: I absolutely cannot have a task run at 2 different schedules without having a duplicate task entry. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's supported out of the box, but it looks fairly doable to write a custom schedule. Celery supports [crontab](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules) and [solar](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#solar-schedules) schedules, and they are Python classes so I assume one could create its own.

I haven't tested it, but it looks like it should be something along the lines of:

```py
import calendar
import datetime

from celery.schedules import BaseSchedule, schedstate

class last_day_month(BaseSchedule):

    def is_due(self, last_run_at):
        """Return tuple of ``(is_due, next_time_to_run)``.

        Note:
            next time to run is in seconds.

        See Also:
            :meth:`celery.schedules.schedule.is_due` for more information.
        """
        # Same as the one from crontab schedule class
        rem_delta = self.remaining_estimate(last_run_at)
        rem = max(rem_delta.total_seconds(), 0)
        due = rem == 0
        if due:
            rem_delta = self.remaining_estimate(self.now())
            rem = max(rem_delta.total_seconds(), 0)
        return schedstate(due, rem)

    def remaining_estimate(self, last_run_at):
        """Estimate of next run time.

        Returns when the periodic task should run next as a
        :class:`~datetime.timedelta`.
        """
        last_run_at = self.maybe_make_aware(last_run_at)
        now = self.maybe_make_aware(self.now())
        if last_run_at.month == now.month:
            # Already run this month: next time is next month
            month = now.month + 1 if now.month < 12 else 1
            year = now.year + 1 if now.month < 12 else 1
        else:
            # Otherwise, should run this month next
            month, year = now.month, now.year
        # We've got the month and year, now get the last day
        _first_day, last_day = calendar.monthrange(year, month)
        # Build the datetime for next run
        next_utc = self.maybe_make_aware(
            datetime.datetime(year=year, month=month, day=last_day)
        )
        # Return the timedelta from now
        return next_utc - now
```

This is to be used in place of the `crontab` class in your Celery schedule